# Using params in GetMapping in Spring results in ambiguous handler method for multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have the following REST endpoints in Spring boot

```
@GetMapping(value = "students", params = {"name"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getByName(@RequestParam final String name) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping(value = "students", params = {"tag"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getByTag(@RequestParam final String tag) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The above handlers work fine for the following requests:

`localhost:8080/test/students?name="Aron"`

`localhost:8080/test/students?tag="player"`

However, whenever I try the following:

`localhost:8060/test/students?name="Aron"&tag="player"`

it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped` and responds with an `HTTP 500`

How can I change this behavior? I want my app to respond only when I get either a `tag` query parameter or a `name` query parameter.
For anything else, I want it to ignore **even if it's a combination** of two parameters.

Why is it throwing the ambiguous error here and how can we handle that?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple method. Use a single method take both name and tag as requestparam then you can handle that  case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@RequestParam(required = false)`:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "students")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(
        @RequestParam(required = false) final String name,
        @RequestParam(required = false) final String tag) {

        if ((name == null) == (tag == null)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you can use negations in params. Something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "students", params = {"name", "!tag"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getByName(@RequestParam final String name) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping(value = "students", params = {"tag", "!name"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getByTag(@RequestParam final String tag) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**References:** [Advanced @RequestMapping options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced)